# Instagram API - Search for user in Sandbox mode

Tags: php, api, instagram

I have difficulty using the `/users/search` endpoint according to the documentation in the Instagram magnificent API. I have Sandbox app set up, I have sandbox users added, I have a valid `access_token`, but when searching, Instagram returns an empty array of data with the `200 code`. Yes, I am sure the users I look for are there.

Has anybody experienced something like this in the past? Last time I've used that feature was about two months ago, and it worked fine.

Could it be some transient glitch, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Since I have the same issue, I did many tests, but I found only a partial solution:

It does not seem to be a sandbox issue, but an API issue. Searching a profile with 23 characters by a search string of 1, 2, ... up to 6 characters doesn't work, however, with 7 characters the API finally found the profile to me.

Based on my own tests, I think it doesn't show because the API considers all the profiles in stock if the profile you are searching is in the first positions in relation the number of characters searched it will be showed or not (I don't know how the API orders them).

Answer (score 0):

In Sandbox mode you will only get response for posts and users that are in your sandbox user list.

So if you search for a username in your sandbox, then only that user will be in API response, once your app is reviewed, approved and live, all the users will show up in API response.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've read the documentation extensively, but the actual behavior of Instagram's API now is quite different. I have 4 sandbox users added. The `/users/search` endpoint returns only my account, if I search for it. If I search for one of my Sandbox users, API returns an empty array. It's wrong, isn't it? It worked about two months ago just fine. I believe there's some immediate issue with the API. I'd like somebody else to confirm it, if it's possible.

Comment: I just checked in my sandbox account and searched for a one of my sandbox user and it comes up in API response. This sandbox account was opened 4 months ago

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I've returned to that part of my app and it still doesn't work. I can only see myself in the Sandbox. I have users invited and functional there in the developer console, but the API doesn't want to return them. Why can that be?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue too iSS...did you manage to find any solution to it?

Comment: after u invite people to sandbox, they have to accept, then you will see them in results